# Golang HTTP request worker pool

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I'm trying to build a system, worker pool / jobqueue, to handle as many `http requests` as possible on each API endpoint. I looked into this [example](http://marcio.io/2015/07/handling-1-million-requests-per-minute-with-golang/) and got it working just fine except that I stumbled upon the problem that I don't understand how to expand the `pool / jobqueue` to different endpoints.

For scenario sake let's sketch an Golang http server that has a million request / min across different endpoints and request types `GET` & `POST` ETC.

How can I expand on this concept? Should I create different worker pools and jobs for each endpoint. Or can I create different jobs and enter them in the same queue and have the same pool handle these?

I want to maintain simplicity where if I create a new API endpoint I don't have to create new worker pools, so I can focus just on the API. But performance is also very much in mind.

The code I'm trying to build on is taken from the example linked earlier, [here](https://github.com/beyazc/job-worker) is a github 'gist' of somebody else with this code.

Comment: Go's http package starts a go routine for each incoming connection. Unless you are talking about background job processing, this seems like wasted effort.

Comment: Yes correct this is for background processing. Some that might take quit a while to finish and I rather not let a uncontrolled amount of goroutines loose

Comment: What's the problem with goroutines? They are basically the build-in implementation of jobqueues with async support.

Comment: Because I wish to control the amount of goroutines. I rather not get a spike of request and fire up uncontrolled amount of goroutines, especially related to HTTP requests which with too many it just starts spewing errors of too many concurrent http connections.

Comment: It's actually up to you. If you need to have a fair(er) worker pool it makes sense to have one per specific work scenario (endpoint). Imagine what would happen if you have 2 endpoints and one of them producing 100x more work items than the second endpoint...
[Edit] If you do want to stick to a single worker pool, you can implement it so that it acts as a scheduler that has a queue per endpoint and that sequentially checks each queue for work (or uses some clever load balancing).

Comment: Why do you need a worker pool? This sounds like lots of extra work (and overhead) for no gain.

Comment: I'm a student trying to understand the concept of worker pools related to different kind of jobs and also I'm learning Go. It's for learning purposes I want to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing up front: If you are running an HTTP server (Go's standard server anyway), you cannot control the number of goroutines without stopping and restarting the server. Each request starts at least one goroutine, and there's nothing you can do about that. The good news is that this is usually not a problem, since goroutines are so lightweight. However, it is perfectly reasonable that you want to keep the number of goroutines that are doing hard work under control.

You can put any value into a channel, including functions. So if the goal is to only having to write code in http handlers, let the jobs be closures -- the workers don't know (or care) what they are working on.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

var largePool chan func()
var smallPool chan func()

func main() {
    // Start two different sized worker pools (e.g., for different workloads).
    // Cancelation and graceful shutdown omited for brevity.

    largePool = make(chan func(), 100)
    smallPool = make(chan func(), 10)

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            go func() {
                    for f := range largePool {
                            f()
                    }
            }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            go func() {
                    for f := range smallPool {
                            f()
                    }
            }()
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/endpoint-1", handler1)
    http.HandleFunc("/endpoint-2", handler2) // naming things is hard, okay?

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Imagine a JSON body containing a URL that we are expected to fetch.
    // Light work that doesn't consume many of *our* resources and can be done
    // in bulk, so we put in in the large pool.
    var job struct{ URL string }

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&job); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
    }

    go func() {
            largePool <- func() {
                    http.Get(job.URL)
                    // Do something with the response
            }
    }()

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
}

func handler2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // The request body is an image that we want to do some fancy processing
    // on. That's hard work; we don't want to do too many of them at once, so
    // so we put those jobs in the small pool.

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
    }

    go func() {
            smallPool <- func() {
                    processImage(b)
            }
    }()
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
}

func processImage(b []byte) {}
```

This is a very simple example to get the point across. It doesn't matter much how you setup your worker pools. You just need a clever job definition. In the example above it is a closure, but you could also define a Job interface, for instance.

```
type Job interface {
    Do()
}

var largePool chan Job
var smallPool chan Job
```

---

Now, I wouldn't call the whole worker pool approach "simple". You said your goal is to limit the number of goroutines (that are doing work). That doesn't require workers at all; it only needs a limiter. Here is the same example as above, but using channels as semaphores to limit concurrency.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

var largePool chan struct{}
var smallPool chan struct{}

func main() {
    largePool = make(chan struct{}, 100)
    smallPool = make(chan struct{}, 10)

    http.HandleFunc("/endpoint-1", handler1)
    http.HandleFunc("/endpoint-2", handler2)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var job struct{ URL string }

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&job); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
    }

    go func() {
            // Block until there are fewer than cap(largePool) light-work
            // goroutines running.
            largePool <- struct{}{}
            defer func() { <-largePool }() // Let everyone that we are done

            http.Get(job.URL)
    }()

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
}

func handler2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
    }

    go func() {
            // Block until there are fewer than cap(smallPool) hard-work
            // goroutines running.
            smallPool <- struct{}{}
            defer func() { <-smallPool }() // Let everyone that we are done

            processImage(b)
    }()

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
}

func processImage(b []byte) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need worker pool at all? Would not be goroutines be enough?

If you are limited by resources you can consider implementing [rates limiting](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/RateLimiting). If not why simply not to span go routines as needed?

The best way to learn is to study how others do good stuff.

Have a look at https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp

> Fast HTTP package for Go. Tuned for high performance. Zero memory allocations in hot paths. Up to 10x faster than `net/http`.

They are claiming:

> serving up to 200K rps from more than 1.5M concurrent keep-alive connections per physical server

That is quite impressive and I doubt you can do any better with `pool / jobqueue`.

Comment: fasthttp is fast to the detriment of http standards

Answer (score 0):

As answered before in your server each request handler will run in at least one goroutine.

But you still can use a worker-pool for back-end parallel tasks if necessary. For example let's suppose some of your Http Handler functions triggers calls to other external apis and "aggregates" their results together, so the order of calls does not matter in this case, this is one scenario where you can leverage a worker pool and distribute your work in order to have them run in parallel dispatching each task to a worker goroutine:

Sample code snippet:

```
    // build empty response
    capacity := config.GetIntProperty("defaultListCapacity")
    list := model.NewResponseList(make([]model.Response, 0, capacity), 1, 1, 0)

    // search providers
    providers := getProvidersByCountry(country)

    // create a slice of jobResult outputs
    jobOutputs := make([]<-chan job.JobResult, 0)

    // distribute work
    for i := 0; i < len(providers); i++ {
        job := search(providers[i], m)
        if job != nil {
            jobOutputs = append(jobOutputs, job.ReturnChannel)
            // Push each job onto the queue.
            GetInstance().JobQueue <- *job
        }
    }

    // Consume the merged output from all jobs
    out := job.Merge(jobOutputs...)
    for r := range out {
        if r.Error == nil {
            mergeSearchResponse(list, r.Value.(*model.ResponseList))
        }
    }
    return list
```

. complete example of worker pool running "generic" tasks asynchronously: https://github.com/guilhebl/go-offer/blob/master/offer/repo.go

. worker pool lib used: https://github.com/guilhebl/go-worker-pool

Answer (score 0):

A late answer: I see the benefit of creating a worker pool. While go-routines are light weight, there is still a cost involved in creating a new go-routine. If the back-end system cannot process the go-routine due to a finite computational capacity, there is no point using computational resources to generate more go-routines. The system will function better, if the finite computational resources are used to execute the existing go-routines. I think many people think that because go routines are light weight, a server can generate unlimited go routines which can process tasks. That is simply not true as pointed out in a number of articles (million connections..) Generating a pool of go-routines is a method to limit the number of go-routines and size the  execution of these go-routines in line with the computational resources available to the go run time environment.